# Extract the required substring from another string -Perl

Tags: string, perl, split, grep

I want to extract a substring from a line in Perl.  Let me explain giving an example:

```
fhjgfghjk3456mm   735373653736
icasd 666666666666
111111111111
```

In the above lines, I only want to extract the 12 digit number. I tried using `split` function:

```
my @cc = split(/[0-9]{12}/,$line);
print @cc;
```

But what it does is removes the matched part of the string and stores the residue in `@cc`. I want the part matching the pattern to be printed. How do I that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $1 built-in variable stores the last match from a regex. Also, if you perform a regex on a whole string, it will return the whole string. The best solution here is to put parentheses around your match then print $1.

```
my $strn = "fhjgfghjk3456mm 735373653736\nicasd\n666666666666 111111111111";
$strn =~ m/([0-9]{12})/;
print $1;
```

This makes our regex match JUST the twelve digit number and then we return that match with $1.

Comment: Thanks.. That was pretty simple.. But trust me, I read a lot before posting this question. Thanks a lot..

Comment: You should not use `$1` without a conditional.

Comment: @TLP Why not? This [official Perl page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick#Extracting-matches) does not say anything about needing to use `$1` with a conditional.

Comment: @pacoverflow `perl -lwe'$_ = "asd"; /(a)/; print $1; /(x)/; print $1;'`. Will print `a` twice. Because `$1` contains the capture from the most recent *successful* match. So we add a conditional to avoid ambiguity and false positives.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = 'fhjgfghjk3456mm 735373653736 icasd 666666666666 111111111111';
while ($string =~ m/\b(\d{12})\b/g) {
  say $1;
}
```

Test the regex here: http://rubular.com/r/Puupx0zR9w

```
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/\b(\d+)\b/)->explain();

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\b(\d+)\b)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/perl
my $var = 'fhjgfghjk3456mm 735373653736 icasd 666666666666 111111111111';
if($var =~ m/(\d{12})/) {
  print "Twelve digits: $1.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

undef $/;
$text = <DATA>;
@res = $text =~ /\b\d{12}\b/g;
print "@res\n";

__DATA__
fhjgfghjk3456mm   735373653736
icasd 666666666666
111111111111
```